# how to turn a foreach into a lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, foreach

I know it's very specific but I have a method created to put **Page** into a Treemap in a specific way it work great and I wanted to created another method to do this with multiple pages like this

```java
static void multiplePageAdder(TreeMap<String, Page> t, Page... myPages){
        for (Page p: myPages) {
            onePageAdder(t,p); //static void onePageAdder(TreeMap<String,Page> t,Page p)
        }
    }
```

I'm pretty sure I could turn this into a lambda expression but I don't know how, could you help me ?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re trying to do.  You can’t have more than one Page per key if the Map’s type is `<String, Page>`.

Comment: @VGR It looks like recursion but notice that inside loop OP calls `pageAdder` not `page*s*Adder`

Comment: @Pshemo Ah, good catch, I glossed right over that.

Comment: yeah sorry I'll change it

Comment: You can rewrite your code into something like `Arrays.stream(myPages).forEach(p->onePageAdder(t,p));` but I am not sure why would you want that. What you have now is IMO clear enough and will work with similar performance as stream. BTW lambda is only this part `p->onePageAdder(t,p)`, what I wrote earlier is stream pipeline.

Comment: Basically in java, what we call lambdas are functional interfaces used with a specific syntax. Lambdas as they are in python for example don’t exist. So one trick is to instantiante a Function class of type TreeMap or whatever you want and use it as a lambda. Btw as @VGR said, this looks like an infinite recursive loop

Comment: it is not recursive it's just that I wanted a method to do it with one pages but also another to do it with multiple pages

Answer (score 0):

thank to @Pshemo I learned to Use `Arrays.stream()` and like he proposed I used

```java
Arrays.stream(myPages).forEach(p->onePageAdder(t,p));
```